# Conditional formatting to change background (colour) and text (wording) in another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I really need help in Excel 2013, using Conditional Formatting (I think). I have a few worksheets that I need to draw data from in a summary page. In this summary page obviously I need to use colour, which I can do, but to further complicate things, I'm trying to find out that if a cell in, call it worksheet 2:

shows `1`, the summary worksheet must not only change colour, but it must replace the number `1` with `ship` - cell colour green.
If the cell says `2`, the summary page must say `road`, and cell colour orange,
if the cell says `3`, summary page must say `air` and change colour to red.

Is there anyway that it can be done this way?

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of formulas and conditional formatting. Say Sheet1 has the summary and Sheet2 has the numbers you mention in cell A1. In Sheet1 you can use a formula

=CHOOSE(Sheet2!A1,"ship","road","air")

Use conditional formatting in Sheet1 to color based on the text the cell contains. Select cell A1 and create three formats that use formulas like

```
=A1="ship"   -> Format green
=A1="road"   -> format orange
=a1="air"    -> format red
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that it can be done this way?

Yes but, with this proposal, subject to there being content in summary sheet to begin with. `0` in each cell to be formatted would suffice. Say the formatting is to be applied to ColumnA, please select Column A and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
='worksheet 2'!A1=1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Fill, green, and for Number, Custom:

```
"ship"
```

OK, OK.

As above `='worksheet 2'!A1=2`, orange and `"road"`.
As above `='worksheet 2'!A1=3`, red and `"air"`.

To hide any `0`s that are not formatted, select ColumnA and Custom Format:

```
0;0;;
```

All the above assuming a one-to-one relationship for the rows between the sheets, so if A3 in worksheet 2 has `3`, then that would trigger A3 in the summary sheet to be red/air.